# Karate: Compare 2 JSON responses and ignore the dateformat

Tags: karate

I have to compare two JSON responses, Date format will be different in both the JSONs. Match is failing as the date format is different. Is there any way where I can ignore Date format and do the comparison?

JSON1:
{
"totalSize": 1,
"data": [
{
"additionalInformation": {
"sourceType": "name-date",
"descriptionValues": {
"appointment_date": "2020-10-01"
},
"actionDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
"transactionId": "M3MmFkaXF6a2N4"
},
"filingDate": "2020-10-05",
"endDate": "2020-10-05",
"document": {
"imageType": "types"
},
"company": {
"name": ""
},
"language": "EN",
"startDate": "2020-10-05"
}
]
}

JSON2:
{
"totalSize": 1,
"data": [
{
"additionalInformation": {
"sourceType": "name-date",
"descriptionValues": {
"appointment_date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00"
},
"actionDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
"transactionId": "M3MmFkaXF6a2N4"
},
"filingDate": "2020-10-05T00:00:00",
"endDate": "2020-10-05T00:00:00",
"document": {
"imageType": "types"
},
"company": {
"name": ""
},
"language": "EN",
"startDate": "2020-10-05T00:00:00"
}
]
}

Comment: and also **read the docs** on `#ignore`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse date format. if you want to compare date.

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate how to do it? In this JSON many places have dates.

Comment: //If Date is in format YYYY-mm-dd xx:xx:xx
const type1 = new Date('2020-10-01');
const type2 = new Date('2020-10-01T00:00:00');
var options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(type1.toLocaleDateString("hi-IN", options));  
console.log(type2.toLocaleDateString("hi-IN", options));